# Circuit design review - battery powered attiny with Zener voltage regulator

Tags: circuit-design

Would some kind soul review the design of my circuit? I have a couple of design challenges. I'm using a ATtiny85 with a voltage range of 5.5 V to blink a [UV LED](http://www.bivar.com/Portals/0/Products/d.ashx?f=/Portals/0/products/SM1206UV-395-IL.pdf) with a forward voltage of 3.7 V. It will be battery powered, and I cant use a single cell because it wont achieve the needed forward voltage of the LED.

So, D1 is a [Schottky diode](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/408/1SS404_datasheet_en_20140301-740963.pdf) intended to protect against accidentally installed the battery backwards. D2 is a [zener](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/427/plzseries-947731.pdf) that is intended to serve a voltage regulator similar to this [tutorial](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_7.html). It's meant to keep voltage < 5.1 V.

The ATtiny85 will be programmed using a clamp-on ISP programmer, so there's no connector designed into the circuit.

[image]

How'd I do? Does everything seem okay?

Comment: You don't write about your current requirements, but I'd suggest you consider the modest addition of a BJT and the use of a 5.6 V zener rather than a 5.1 V zener. What are your thoughts about this? (I assume you've seen such a case from your searches, already.)

Comment: So the question seems to be if the current requirements of the LED exceeds the attiny85? I read that the attiny85 can handle 40mA, the LED forward current is 25mA, so it seems like it's okay as is. I certainly can use a 5.6V zener, what's your thinking there?

Comment: You probably don't need \$D_1\$ unless you are worried about putting in the battery backwards. (In which case it might be useful.) The zener you use will have a nominal current that it needs to be flowing through it. You should try to meet those specifications with your resistor. (I didn't look it up.) The problem I was talking about is that even if everything works, your LED may use 20 mA and that must come through that resistor. And it can't. You really need a BJT or else an LDO, I suppose.

Comment: @jonk - yes, D1 is for polarity protection.

Comment: @Owen White: if you can't add an LDO or a transistor because of tight space constraints or other reasons, you *might* get away with removing the resistor altogether, picking D1 with a higher Vf and adjusting the zener so that the sum of voltages on D1 and D2 does not go below V_BAT (with some margin as V_BAT may be higher than 6.0V).

Comment: @A.K. could you expand on that, I dont know how to select the D1 and D2 combination. Are you suggesting selecting a D1 with a voltage drop that takes me from 6v to 5.5 or something?

Comment: @Owen White: basically, yes. Choose a diode with voltage drop of say 1V. Although I would not recommend doing that, unless absolutely necessary. There will be no regulation. D2 will be actually useless then since it will see no current flowing.

Comment: Related :https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337450/question-regarding-lm5113-driver/337462#337462

Comment: okay so it seems that what youre saying is consistent with the current design, except remove the 22k.  I think D1 would have a voltage drop of .4V, and D2 is supposed to regulate at 5.1. Just go with what I have an lose 22k?

Comment: @Owen White: you cannot *efficiently* regulate voltage with a zener in a circuit that has high and variable current consumption. You cannot drop R and leave D2 because if Vbat > Vf + Vzener, you'll have a short circuit, otherwise zener will do nothing. If you want regulation, replace R with R=(Vbat_min - Vf_d1 - Vf_led ) / I_LED - 330 Ohm. The problem with this is that the whole circuit will always consume the maximum current regardless of whether LED is on or off. I ignore current consumption of Attiny because otherwise the formula will be more complicated. In short, use an LDO.

Answer (score 3):

[Jonathan already answered](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/338095/139766) your question with significant detail.

However, you can save yourself a lot of bother, and battery life, if you redesign it like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9iAdc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thanks, that is really helpful. Any chance you could suggest an OEM coin cell battery holder that would let me jump between the two cells, I havent seen one. Wait - I guess I could use two separate holders.

Comment: one last question - I need to put in a switch - can it go between bat2 and ground? Or will there be still be some drain of bat1 through D2?

Comment: @OwenWhite If it is a power switch, you have two choices, either on ground or in-series with D2. The top battery can not back drive the ATTiny through that transistor and the transistor will stay off so no current will go through the LED.

Comment: great. Thanks a lot this is a really nice design, I'll be translating into a PCB soon.

Comment: @OwenWhite you are welcome.. invoice is in the mail ;)

Comment: Hey! @Trever I ordered up the PCBs and the circuit worked wonderfully. Here's a [pic](https://i.imgur.com/h9PFvqp.png). The board ended up being 26x13mm, and essentially came down to the size of two coin cell batteries. Thanks again!

Comment: @OwenWhite nice :) Thanks for the feedback. Always good to hear how it ended up.

Answer (score 2):

That won't work at all.

The resistor / zener regulator will constantly draw current from the battery, draining it slowly even when the controller isn't doing anything. Depending on the intended lifetime of the battery, that might be an issue or not.

The bigger problem is that any time your controller switches on the LED, its supply voltage will drop dramatically and the LED will just barely glow. The 330 Ohms series resistor of the LED forms a voltage divider with the 22k resistor that's in series with the battery. When the LED is on, it'll just pull down the supply voltage because the 22k resistor limits the available current to almost nothing. Additionally, the controller might crash from the sudden voltage drop.

You should use a low-dropout 5V linear regulator. Alternatively, you could attach the LED to the positive terminal of the battery directly and then pull it down to ground through the controller. Then you could keep using the weak zener regulator for the controller. Don't forget to put some decoupling capacitors on the supply rails.

Edit: If the LED should just blink at a constant frequency, you could also simply use a NE555 timer IC instead of the microcontroller. That wouldn't need any voltage regulator at all since the NE555 can operate from 6V directly.

Edit 2, explanation of why there's a voltage divider formed: When the controller switches on the LED, the current has to flow through the following path: Positive battery terminal, D1 (schottky), 22k resistor, microcontroller, 330 Ohm resistor, LED, negative battery terminal. The output current of the controller's pins has to come from somewhere, and that "somewhere" is the controller's Vdd pin. Which has the 22k resistor in series with it. Therefore the 22k and 330 Ohm resistors are in series, forming a voltage divider.

Comment: neat idea connecting the LED on the high side of the MCU. However, wouldn't it inject voltage >Vdd through the I/O pin?

Comment: @A.K. It won't due to the high forward voltage of the LED. With 6V battery voltage and 5V at the MCU, the voltage across the LED is just 1V and no significant current will flow. And even if there was some current, the zener would take care of it.

Comment: I agree that the current will be tiny. However, 3.7V is a forward voltage at nominal current, it approaches zero at I -> 0. In the general case, if we have say 3.3V tolerant I/O, is it okay to subject it to higher voltage through a high-value resistor? I don't understand this clearly.

Comment: @A.K. The voltage at the I/O pin will not be greater than the supply voltage because the pin is an output and switched to Vdd when the LED is off. Even if it's an input instead, the protection diodes of the pin will take over the current, so yes, it's okay to subject a digital IC's pins to a higher voltage through a high-value resistor. Most datasheets will mention this. Additionally, at 1V, the LED current will probably be smaller than the leakage current through any flux residue on the board. (LED current rises exponentially with voltage.)

Comment: @Jonathan S. - A voltage divider is formed between the 330 ohm and 20k? How? That seems counter to a larger number of circuits I've seen using MCUs. Regarding the suggestion to use a 5V regulator I had read previously they were inefficient so I was looking for an alternative to save battery power. Regarding the zener draining the battery, it's only meant to run when the LED is running. I dont want to go with a 555, this is meant to pulse the LED with PWM.

Comment: @OwenWhite When the controller switches on the LED, the current has to flow through the following path: Positive battery terminal, D1 (schottky), 22k resistor, microcontroller, 330 Ohm resistor, LED, negative battery terminal. The output current of the controller's pins has to come from somewhere, and that "somewhere" is the controller's Vdd pin. Which has the 22k resistor in series with it. Therefore the 22k and 330 Ohm resistors are in series, forming a voltage divider. You're also wasting more power with the zener regulator than with a linear one due to its high idle current.